# Formatting java strings with system.out.printf

Tags: java, printf, output, system.out

I've been looking around at a lot of questions about the System.out.printf in java for formatting string outputs and I just don't seem to understand how to use it.

I'm trying to print nice columns that looks like this

```
601 GoPro Hero5 Black       276.95
602 GoPro Hero5 Session     199.00
611 Canon EOS Rebel         361.89
```

but the best I can get is this

```
601 GoPro Hero5 Black     276.95
602 GoPro Hero5 Session     199.00
611 Canon EOS Rebel     361.89
```

I seem to be able to align the first two values but never the third. Here is my code

```
System.out.printf("%-1s %10s %10.2f\n", "ex string", "ex string", 276.95);
```

I thought the "-1s" was left align for minus, and 1 would be the space between the first and second input, then %10s would be ten characters apart, the %10.2 would be ten apart with 2 decimal places. So I tried to do

```
System.out.printf("%-1s %10s %20.2f\n", "ex string", "ex string", 276.95);
```

but this still doesn't get those third values inline with one another.

---

Revised attempt using

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %10.2f\n", "ex string", "ex string", 276.95);
```

results in...

```
601        GoPro Hero5 Black     276.95
602        GoPro Hero5 Session     199.00
611        Canon EOS Rebel     361.89
```

---

for the record my code is getting the variables like this:

```
System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %10.2f\n", items.get(i).getItemNumber(), items.get(i).getName(), items.get(i).getPrice());
```

Comment: refer https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-right-padding-a-string-with-spaces-and-zeros/

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you, although I need the location to be absolute, not just padding since each string is of different length right?

Comment: The padding amount should be big enough to fit the largest `String`, so if you wanted to padd `A`, `BB`, `CCC` then provide a format padding of `4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field width specifiers are not spacing specs.

`%-1` means left align in a field at least one character wide. But your first column is always at least 3 characters wide, so the specifier is ignored. The first column comes out looking neat purely by coincidence: all your numbers happen to have three digits.

Similarly, `%10` means right align in a field at least 10 characters wide. But all your camera names are much longer than that, so the specifier is effectively ignored.

You are probably looking for something more like

```
%-4s%-25s%6.2f
```

This means:

1. Left align the first argument in a field at least 4 characters wide
2. Left align the second argument in a field at least 25 characters wide
3. Print the number right aligned, with two digits after the decimal point, in a field at least 6 characters wide

You could replace `%4s` with `%3s<space>` for a similar effect. The difference would be in how overflow is handled. The first version would not have a space following values in the first column that were longer than 3 characters. The second one would.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this explanation was very helpful!

Comment: Glad it helped. Not sure why you were thinking it was a spacing spec, but now you know what's going on.