# How do I add width to a System.out.print

Tags: java

I am trying to create a multiplication table where I want the width of every number in the table to not be a constant (i.e. "%3d") and rather be dependent of the user's input. Right now I am using the length of the highest number in the multiplication table. So for example if the highest number in the table is 100, the width of every number in the table should be 3 symbols long. The expression I use to get that number is "int width = String.valueOf(yAxis * xAxis).length();".

How can I implement that width to my table? Right now I am only focusing on one line of the multiplication table, namely the xAxis

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("y:");
    int yAxis = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("x:");
    int xAxis = scan.nextInt();

    int width = String.valueOf(yAxis * xAxis).length();

    for(int i = 0; i < xAxis+1; i++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }


}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%" + width + "d", i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the String.format method:

e.g.

```
String.format("|%20d|", 93);
```

prints something like |                             93|

Answer (score 0):

To print in block format, you can use the `System.out.printf` function. There are already questions which have answers, e.g. have a look at this question:
[Formatting java strings with system.out.printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49604275/formatting-java-strings-with-system-out-printf)